# PHP: Get key from array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I am sure that this is super easy and built-in function in PHP, but I have yet not seen it.

Here's what I am doing for the moment:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; // Would output "subkey" in the example array
    print_r($value);
}
```

Could I do something like the following instead and thereby save myself from writing "$key => $value" in every foreach loop? (psuedocode)

```
foreach($array as $subarray) {
    echo arrayKey($subarray); // Will output the same as "echo $key" in the former example ("subkey"
    print_r($value);
}
```

Thanks!

The array:

```
Array
(
    [subKey] => Array
        (
            [value] => myvalue
        )

)
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `foreach($array as $key => $value)`? Or, asked the other way around, what's the point using `foreach($array as $value)` when you actually need `$key` somewhere down the road?

Comment: I just thought it could be a good idea to get the key in a quick way

Comment: But you do get it in a quick way with `foreach($array as $key => $value)`... :-) Or is the situation not that you are in a foreach loop?

Comment: I am in a foreach loop for sure, but what i've thought about was to not change the foreach statement, but just printing out the key.

Comment: Every function call you could make would be less efficient than simply changing to the appropriate foreach loop construct.

Comment: @Tomalak: I totally agree with you. It doesn't even make sense to transform foreach loops to while loops for getting the key's name (or index) - in reverse (so the opposite of what Industrial would like to do!), it would do make sense!

Comment: @sk8erpeter it's always a question of control over the normal loop behavior: if you want to jump certain keys due to the value of the current key, your `foreach` needs to store the value in some other variable and use conditions for the next values (therefore less efficient)... In a `while` like _vtorhonen_ posted, you only need `if($element=='jump3')next(next(next($array)))`

Comment: @Armfoot: I hope you're just kidding (because this argument seems like BS). I think the overhead of your `next(next(next($array)))` calls is much-much higher (therefore less efficient) than "storing the value in some other variable" and using a foreach loop in the usual `$key=>$value` form...not to mention that the code you showed is way too ugly to use it anywhere.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter well, it's not the "storing in some other variable", it's `testing` it on subsequent array keys and `continue` to the next ones in a `foreach`... We can all be speculating how efficient one will be against the other in many different cases and how heavy a pointer shifter can be (`next`... nanoseconds difference? Algorithm efficiency is normally thought through logic) but that's not my point. My point is: you may have a different purpose for your loop, where you actually want to jump several keys according to specific ones so you don't need to worry about conditions for other keys.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4
);

while($element = current($array)) {
    echo key($array)."\n";
    next($array);
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to add that you can use key() ANYWHERE but for this problem it make sense to use it in a while-loop. You can use key() in the instance of only wanting the first/current array element's key.

Comment: @Industrial `foreach` uses the key... if you want to use foreach, do this: `foreach($array as $key => $value) { ... }`

Answer (score 48):

Use the [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function.

**Example from php.net**

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

Answer (score 40):

```
$foo = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'ball', 'c' => 'coke');

foreach($foo as $key => $item) {
  echo $item.' is begin with ('.$key.')';
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 7):

If it IS a `foreach` loop as you have described in the question, using `$key => $value` is fast and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be in a `foreach` loop, then `foreach($array as $key => $value)` is definitely the recommended approach.  Take advantage of simple syntax when a language offers it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use key($array) in a foreach loop is by using next($array) at the end of the loop, just make sure each iteration calls the next() function (in case you have complex branching inside the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $nmkey)
    {
        echo $nmkey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution that you can add to your Array library. All you need to do is supply the associated value and the target array!

[PHP Manual: array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) (similiar to .indexOf() in other languages)

```
public function getKey(string $value, array $target)
{
    $key = array_search($value, $target);

    if ($key === null) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid arguments provided. Check inputs. Must be a (1) a string and (2) an array.");
    }

    if ($key === false) {
        throw new DomainException("The search value does not exists in the target array.");
    }

    return $key;
}
```