# foreach in array without keys like [0] ->

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a blackout, i have an array ($array) like this:

```
Array
(
    [Resume] => Array
        (
            [lang] => en
            [web] => http://
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [IdValue] => 222
                )
         )
)
```

how i can get only the value of [IdValue]

Comment: You need to tag the language.

Comment: By accessing it, not sure where you are stuck. Can you show the code you have right now?

Comment: i dont know how to accessing it

Comment: if key is fixed then $array['Resume']['id']['IdValue']

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317856/php-get-key-from-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look more into PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). But if I assume your example is in PHP then you can read it like this:

```
$myVar = Array // your array definition
// (
//  Resume] => Array
//     (
//         [lang] => en
//         [web] => http://
//         [id] => Array
//             (
//                 [IdValue] => 222
//             )
//      )
// )

echo $myVar['Resume']['id']['IdValue']; // prints 222
```

Comment: i know now what i am doing bad. my array ist not an array, it is a string. is there an option to convert this string to array?

Comment: If string is JSON / Serialized array then yes using function like `json_decode`, `unserialize`. But output you have provided looks like `print_r` output and there is no standard function to turn it back to array unless you write your own.