# PHP get array_diff key

Tags: php

Array1:

> array('13','15','19');

Array2:

> array('13','19');

Expected output:

> 2

Program:

```
$array1 = array('13','15','19');
$array2 = array('13','19');
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

array_diff giving me value which value is different but instead it I want key. How can I get key?

Comment: Why `2`? The key of 15 is `1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Get key from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317856/php-get-key-from-array) I reckon this covers all the bases.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for :

```
$array1 = array('13','15',17,'19',21);
$array2 = array('13','19');
print_r(array_keys(array_diff($array1, $array2)));
```

which will print you 1,2 and 4 - the keys. (remember "1" means second, because we're starting with 0 key)