# remove subarrays in an array php

Tags: php

I have an array like this

There are more arrays inside the array that I need to remove

```
$arr = [
  "4",
  "10" => [
    [
      "id" => "standard", 
      "name" => "Standard"
    ],
    [
      "id" => "standard_2.0", 
      "name" => "Standard 2.0"
      ]
  ],
  "11" => [
    [
      "id" => "gold", 
      "name" => "Gold"
    ],
    [
      "id" => "gold_2.0", 
      "name" => "Gold 2.0"
      ]
  ],
];
```

How can I remove all subarrays so that it stays like this?

```
$arr = ["4", "10", "11"];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Get key from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317856/php-get-key-from-array)

Comment: Might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   
   if(is_array($value)){
    $newarray[] = $key;
   }else{
     $newarray[] = $value;
   }
  
}
 echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarray);
echo "</pre>";
```